# iterating dynamically over the list

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I have a method as shown below:

```
List<AbcObject> aaList= session.createCriteria(AbcObject.class)
```

`aaList` contains elements like so:

```
t_id   value
11      3
12      20
14      60
15      27    ------->(3+20+60+27=100), here min=11 & max=15
18      40  
22      20
33      40
45      20   -------->(40+20+40+20=100), here min=18 & max=45
```

I have to iterate the list such that if the running total of `value` reaches 100, then an element will be added to another list like so:

```
min     max
11      15
18      45
```

Note that the `100` value on which division is done needs to be configurable.

It can also happen that the value of the first element itself is 100.  In that case `min` and `max`  would have the same value.

I have come up with the below approach:

```
final int BARRIER = 100;

//I am going to assume there are getter methods in your AbcObject and 
//that all values are greater than 0
List<int[]> minMaxs = new List<int[]>();
int sum = 0; 
int min = 0;
for (AbcObject obj: aaList) {
    if (sum == 0) {
        //start over, remember min
        min = obj.getT_id();
    }
    //add value to sum
    sum += obj.getValue();
    if (sum >= BARRIER) {
        //now we need to start again, remember what we got
        minMaxs.add(new int[]{min, obj.getT_id()});
        //reset
        min = 0;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

A different approach I have found is:

```
final int BARRIER = 100;

//I am going to assume there are getter methods in your AbcObject and 
//that all values are greater than 0
List<AbcObject> minMaxs = new List<AbcObject>();
int sum = 0; 
int min = 0;
for (AbcObject obj: aaList) {
    if (sum == 0) {
        //start over, remember min
        min = obj.getT_id();
    }
    //add value to sum
    sum += obj.getValue();
    if (sum >= BARRIER) {
        //now we need to start again, remember what we got
        minMaxs.add(new AbcObject(min, obj.getT_id()));
        //reset
        min = 0;
        sum = 0;
    }
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Comment: The two code blocks look very similar...

Comment: @keuleJ The first one uses an `int[]` and the second uses an `abcObject`. Otherwise they're identical.

Comment: Folks I agree as the there is not much difference between the two code blocks but the point is what other strategy I can approach here whic will be better thn this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly reasonable and is easy to understand. I see no pressing need for changes.